# Performance issue with order by clause

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle11g

I have below query which returns 20000 records from 100000000 after executing it..

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
          FROM (select TIME,url,bytes 
                  FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR ("5mintime",'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIME, url, BYTES 
                          FROM available_web_details  
                         WHERE "5mintime" >= TIMESTAMP '2012-02-10 00:00:00' 
                           AND "5mintime" <= TIMESTAMP '2012-02-13 23:59:59' 
                           AND username = 'asha1328874833' 
                           AND CATEGORY = 'None240001'AND domain = '1328874833.vmware.com.'
                           AND (appid IN ('216.198.204.192id','216.198.207.0id','216.198.211.64id','216.198.211.128id','216.198.212.0id', '216.198.214.128id','216.198.214.192id','216.198.218.0id','216.198.220.192id','216.198.222.0id','216.198.223.32id','216.198.228.128id','216.198.229.128id',.....))) 
                      ORDER BY TIME DESC) a 
                 WHERE ROWNUM <= 10) 
         WHERE rnum > 0
```

It takes around 5 minutes to execute it. But when I remove the order by clause, it executes in 4 seconds. Can you suggest how can I improve the performance?

**schema of available_web_details:**

```
Name         Null   Type           
------------ ---- -------------- 
5mintime          TIMESTAMP(6)   
USERNAME          VARCHAR2(64)   
HOST              NUMBER         
SRC_ZONE          VARCHAR2(32)   
DOMAIN            VARCHAR2(512)  
DST_ZONE          VARCHAR2(32)   
CONTENT           VARCHAR2(64)   
CATEGORY          VARCHAR2(64)   
URL               VARCHAR2(1024) 
HITS              NUMBER         
BYTES             NUMBER         
APPID             VARCHAR2(32)   
APPLICATION       VARCHAR2(64)   
CATEGORYTYPE      VARCHAR2(64)   
USERGROUP         VARCHAR2(384)
```

I have indexes on **appid, "5mintime"** with local partition. The `available_web_details` is range partition table of 1 month.

Comment: Have you thought about indexing?

Comment: @roymustang86: Why do you waste our time with your worthless suggested edit?

Comment: Can you take out the `rnum > 0` clause? I'm pretty sure that will do nothing.

Comment: @eaolson, it's there so that for the second page Asha can select where `rownum <= 20` then where `rownum > 10`

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the disclaimer: if you don't remove that `order by` or start using temp tables, the execution time is **never** going to reduce to 4s. Second disclaimer: I made a big mistake that I'm now correcting; took me too long to realise it. Thank you [Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole).

My points ( I always have several ).

1. Some very valid points have been raised in the comments, specifically by [DimitryB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9441676/458741). If you're only displaying 10 records at a time then 20,000 rows equals 2,000 pages. No human is going to bother looking at all that information. You can very safely reduce the number of records returned to 500 if not one or two hundred.
2. An equally valid point was raised by [craigmj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9441680/458741), though I would like to significantly extend it. By not indexing **everything** in the `where` clause **and** everything in the `select` you **guarantee** a `table access by index rowid`. This means that for every single row you return from your innermost `select` you have pulled from the index you also re-access the table. I recognise that this would be a ridiculously big index on your current table though.
3. You seem to be doing one more sub-select than is needed. You can put your order by in the main `select`. You're also referencing the alias `a` at two levels above the alias. While this probably won't cause any problems, it's a little confusing and you end up with the column `rnum` twice.
4. 100m rows is getting towards the *large* end of the spectrum. The chances of anyone paging through all of these is unlikely and from your comments they're not all used in the reports. Whilst the table is partitioned, which will help a lot, Oracle still has to work out which partition to use.
5. Following on from point 5, you've partitioned the table by month but are only selecting 3 days worth of data. I agree that this is sensible but if you only need a months worth of data maximum to be *easily* accessible it might be worth partitioning by day for a smaller table? You mentioned that 2,300 reports use this table; if they're all taking 5 minutes then drastic methods, such as this, should be considered.
6. It's a little pathetic but is there any need for `url` to be 1024 characters?

**These points effectively boil down to my main suggestion; *reduce the size of the table.*** Then, do everything possible to remove any extra work Oracle needs to do; even to turning most of the table into an index.

So, the steps would be:

- Archive off everything that is greater than one month old into a separate table. Keep doing this on a daily basis.
- Partition the smaller table by day.
- If you only need a few days of data it will definitely be worth considering creating a [materialized view](http://psoug.org/reference/materialized_views.html), with the order by already in place.
- Use the *"optimal"* index on this new, smaller, table; so you never have to actually touch the table at all. I've put inverted commas around optimal as this is always open to debate and my suggestion may be slightly incorrect but generally it is **all columns** in the `where, group by, order by and select clauses` in that order **and** in order of decreasing selectivity. This would make your index something like`"5mintime", username, category, domain, appid, url, bytes`.
- Make the index unique if at all possible.
- Ensure your query is not doing anything it doesn't need to in order to reduce the workload. This include returning a human-readable number of rows. I would rewrite it like this:

---

```
SELECT time, url, bytes, rownum as rnum
  FROM ( SELECT time, url, bytes, rowum as rnum 
           FROM ( SELECT TO_CHAR ("5mintime",'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS time
                       , url
                       , bytes 
                    FROM available_web_details  
                   WHERE "5mintime" BETWEEN to_timestamp('2012-02-10 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                            AND to_timestamp('2012-02-13 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                     AND username = 'asha1328874833' 
                     AND category = 'None240001'
                     AND domain = '1328874833.vmware.com.'
                     AND appid IN ('216.198.204.192id',...) 
                   ORDER BY "5mintime" DESC
                         )
         WHERE rownum <= 10) 
 WHERE rnum > 0
```

Hopefully this all makes sense; at the end of the day the amount of work being done on the server by your reports and the speed at which you wish them to run will dictate what you want to do.

Comment: Are your `to_char`s in the where clause supposed to be the `to_timestamp`s from your fourth point? And does the `to_char` in the `order by` have any impact over using the raw column, either positive or negative?

Comment: @AlexPoole, thank you; I didn't catch that on my re-read. For your second point yes, you're correct it would be quicker, but it would also increase the index size as you'd have to index it, so I don't think it would result in a speed improvement.

Comment: the above one is only one report query .we have plenty of such query in same table for different reports in which the condition of where clause changes.so if i create index on each field which are used where,order by,group by and select clause.it might cover all combination of table fields..!!!!!so is it feasible to do..??

Comment: @AshaKoshti, if you don't reduce the size of the table then no; it's not feasible. If you do then it might be. I can't be certain as I don't have access to your DB but it's something that's worth investigating.

Comment: please specify how will i reduce the size of the table..??

Comment: @AshaKoshti, I did :-). If you create an identical table, with a different name. Insert everything with a later date into this table and then delete from your original table, your original table would be smaller. I would test it first by creating a smaller table with only the data you need and follow my other suggestions... but note the point at the top as well.

Comment: ye..sure..thanks to help..post here whenver you are over with it,,

Comment: it will be better if you can suggest hints for this above query for increasing the performance..

Comment: @AshaKoshti, what sort of hint are you after. I'm not sure that index hints will help you. As I say at the top I think the order by will always be a killer and the best way to sort this out is by changing the database, not just the query.

Comment: @Ben,i dont understand the meaning..best way to sort this out is by changing the database????

Comment: @AshaKoshti, that is my suggestion. I would test it first though... if you create a table with the specs I suggest and test how long your query takes you will know whether this is a good idea or not. I can't test it for you unfortunately. I may be completely wrong but from what you described in your question this is the direction I would go down initially.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing order by from Time to 5mintime, I am pretty sure you are not using the index when you are converting the value and sorting on that.

Comment: ye.. i have done that also in above query by replacing time with 5mintime and i m having index on 5mintime but still it is not giving the performance as the same..by latest i should be able to complete it in 30 to 45 seconds..can u suggest some hints or so..

Comment: ordering is going to be a performance penalty either way - you can not expect the same performance as without the order by clause.

Comment: ye..that's true..but i have JSPs to show this result in the pagination..so at every page it hits the same query only bu changing the rownum field from 10,20,30...so on..so having very poor performance of the application.

Comment: hmm  perhaps you need rethink the query. what use is it to scroll through 20K rows at 10 rows at a time :)

Comment: other options can be a materialized view that can be refreshed every hour, then its like a straight select from a table.

Comment: hmm.10 rows at a time..so same query is given to db everytime as user going forward or backward through pages..any idea what to do..??

Comment: I already mentioned a Materialized View - they are very simple to use.

Comment: but this is not the single query that runs everytime..we have 2300 reports and same case is happening in all..so is it good to create this many materalized view per reports..??

Comment: yes. or use a reporting solution that is built to handle it (Cognos, QlickView, etc). The other thing you can do is put your data in a SOLR index - its very fast to return top 10 rows of whatever.

Comment: the above one is only one report query .we have plenty of such query in same table for different reports in which the condition of where clause changes.so if i create index on each field which are used where,order by,group by and select clause.it might cover all combination of table fields..!!!!!so is it feasible to do..??

Comment: I suppose you can add more indexes :). Have you looked at perhaps caching strategies? JPA, Hibernate, EhCache, Toplink will offer some level of caching even on the queries

Comment: we can create indexes on table.but it affects to our insert and deletion queries...so index creation is going to take huge time..

Answer (score 0):

You've got an index on 5mintime, so order by on that, then do the `TO_CHAR` conversion in the outermost select. You could also consider indexing on the other fields that you use in `WHERE` clauses.

Another idea is to look at the query plan that Oracle is using, to see how it is approaching the problem. Here's a good tutorial on Oracle's `explain plan`: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/explainplan.html

Comment: ye.. i have done that also in above query by replacing time with 5mintime and i m having index on 5mintime but still it is not giving the performance as the same..by latest i should be able to complete it in 30 to 45 seconds..can u suggest some hints or so.

Comment: I've edited in a link to an explain plan tutorial - that should show you how Oracle is approaching the query, and let you determine which indexes are used and which you might need to create to get the best performance.